# Mongodb atlas backup/export data auto

Tags: mongodb

I'm using Atlas mongodb

When I try to set a back it says `Turn on Backup (M10 and up)` which means that I cannot backup (Logical Size928.8 KB).

Is there a different method to backup Atlas mongodb?

I know that  I can use Compas to export each collection but it's tedious, I would like to have simple method to backup my data daily, preferable automatic.

Is there a similar service I can use that offer backup for smaller DB as well?